# is preventDefault() a jQuery function or a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

Hi my question is really simple.

Can I use `event.preventDefault();` without jQuery if I am using AngularJS and jqLite, or do I need jQuery to use this function? If I don't want to use jQuery do I need to do `event.returnValue = false;` instead? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` is built into modern browsers (IE9 and greater).  You do not need jQuery to use it so yes, you can just call it directly on your event object assuming you have a standard event object.

The jQuery version of that function was originally created to allow a single programming model while still supporting older versions of IE that did not support it.  If you don't need to support older than IE9, then you can just use the plain JS version on a stock event object.

Comment: @gottfried - I didn't downvote, but perhaps because a small amount of Google research would have turned up the answer to your question.